# can we increase probability of sampling only error/exception spans using sleuth, spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, error-logging, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I want to increase sampling of only those spans which contains error or exception.
If that's possible then how to do that?

I'm using Spring boot(2.2+), sleuth(2.2+) and zipkin(2.2+).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Brave (which is the default) you can register a bean of type `brave.handler.SpanHandler` and over there in the method `end` return false if the `MutableSpan` had any errors.

```
@Component
class ExceptionCheckingSpanHandler extends brave.handler.SpanHandler {

  @Override
  public boolean end(TraceContext context, MutableSpan span, Cause cause) {
    return span.error() != null;
  }

}
```